# Java GUI - actionListener and actionPerformed

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

My question is related to the Java Programming, the GUI concepts. I want to know if I register multiple components such as JButtons, JRadioButtons, JComboBox and JCheckBox in the actionListener which means that I expect these components to perform an action.

Now, in my actionPerformed method, how do I linked all these components to perform an operation. 
For example, if I check a JRadioButton, a JCheckBox and a JButton and I want to display something in aJLabel, like a total.

How do I implement all these components in the actionPeformed method?

Thanking you.. 
Regards,

Comment: Warning to anyone reading this question: don't bother answering, this guy doesn't upvote good answers, but carries on endless comment discussions about how his rudimentary mathematics code doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to vote your answer up ! 
Lool man, are you here seeking for upvotes or helping others ? 
I believe helping others is much more important than begging for votes !
Anyway, thanks for your help ! 
God bless you !

Comment: It's called exchange. People help you, and you give something in return. But you expect people to help you, and you don't give anything back.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method would be to create a `Action` or `ActionListener` per component, which would perform the required job for that component.

This provides isolation and separation of responsibilities, and if you do it right, the possibility for re-use (a `Action` could be applied to a `JMenuItem`, `JButton` on a `JToolbar` and with a Key Binding)

It also makes it easier to replace functionality (replace a single `Action` or `ActionListener` as apposed to re-writing a "mega" `ActionListener`)

Comment: What is the purpose of e.getSource() ?

Comment: The purpose of `getSource` is just that, it's the source of the event.  For example, if you were to define a `Action` which was capable of deleting rows from a `JTable` (via a key binding), you may not want a direct reference to the table, but could use `getSource` to obtain a reference to the table which generated the event.

Comment: Back in the good old days before inner and anonymous classes, it was common practice to bundle unrelated action handling into as few `ActionListener`s as possible (given the fact that either you have to implement the `ActionListener` directly via the parent class or create a sub class).  This was a mess and is very hard to maintain, manage and debug. Now days, it's better practice to provide a single `ActionListener` for each component (where it makes sense to do so)

Comment: You mean like the following example ? 

radio1.addActionListener(this);
radio2.addActionListener(this);
checkbox1.addActionListener(this);
button1.addActionListener(this);

Now, how do I fit the above in the actionPerformed method?

Comment: Yes, and take it from me, this approach is a complete pain. It also exposes your `actionPerformed` method publicly, which in most cases is not desirable

Comment: What do you suggest then ?

Comment: I'm suggesting you use inner classes, anonymous classes and/or Action's. Each listener should be dictated to performing the required task for the required component. You could reuse listeners that provide common functionality (such as form validation for example). Remember, you can add more the one listener to a component. What I'm fighting against is a all encompassing/mega listener

Answer (score 0):

> How do I implement all these components in the actionPeformed method?

To reference a component, create an instance variable.

To implement the `actionPerformed` method, create a class that implements `ActionListener`; this can be an anonymous class or a named class.

In this example, we create two ActionListeners as anonymous inner classes.

**Scratch.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Scratch extends JFrame {
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click Me");
    JCheckBox check1 = new JCheckBox("Check Me");
    JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Select Me");
    JComboBox<String> combo1 = new JComboBox<String>(new String[] {"Choose Me", "No me!"});

    public Scratch() {
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 170));
        setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
        add(radio1);
        add(check1);
        add(combo1);
        add(button1);
        radio1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
                check1.setSelected(!radio1.isSelected());
            }
        });
        button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                combo1.setSelectedIndex(combo1.getSelectedIndex() == 0 ? 1 : 0);
            }
        });
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scratch().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In this partial example, the `Scratch` class itself is an `ActionListener`:

```
public class Scratch extends JFrame
    implements java.awt.event.ActionListener // <- implements ActionListener
{
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click Me");

    public Scratch() {
        // layout, etc.
        add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(this); // <- tell button1 to call my actionPerformed()
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
        Object component = event.getSource(); // which control was clicked?
        if (component == button1) {
            // do something in response to button1 click event
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in this last example, we can use the [`ActionEvent.getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) method to discover which component triggered the event.

Comment: What if I have a button click event and a Radio Button and a Checkbox event ? 
Can all these fit in the actionPerformed method ?

Comment: Yes, if that works better for what you're trying to accomplish. Normally I would have a different event handler method for each component. If you choose to use only one event handler, you can discover which component triggered the event by calling [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) on the `ActionEvent`.

Comment: See with what I have done so far: 

http://pastebin.com/wwtVVwtW

Unfortunately, its not working properly as it should

Comment: `if (park.isSelected())
   sum = 600;
  else if (pool.isSelected())
   sum = 750;
  else if (lake.isSelected())
   sum = 825;
  if (meal.isSelected())
   sum += 200;
  total.setText("$" + sum);`

Comment: We cannot have the && in the condition like if(pool.isSelected() && meal.isSelected()) ?

Comment: Unfortunately its not giving me the desired result